# bypassing "show more" button when web scraping

Tags: html, web-scraping

So im looking at web scraping, but when i go to a url only 60 elements show and i need to click on a "show more" button. Just wondering if there was a way to bypass this and load a url complacently.

Comment: what technology are you using to scrape the page?

Comment: created a python script

Comment: Can you paste the html elements connected to show more button? Btw, you should edit your post with some materials to make it SO specific question otherwise your post will be saturated with downvotes and make sure to add language tag  as well.